# How can I use “fête” as a verb in active voice?

Tags: passive-voice, transitive-verbs, active-voice, is-it-a-verb

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fete?q=fete) cites a verb as an entry for *fête* and gives a passive example. How can I use *fête* in the active voice? For example, can one *fête* an occasion with pomp and circumstance?

Comment: While most instances of *feted* Google search finds are in the passive voice, searching for *feting* yields many results in the active voice.

Comment: The passive sounds better to me, but 'they feted the president on his birthday' works. I don't think you can say 'to fete an occasion' that seems wrong; it's the person that gets fete'ed, that gets the party thrown for them.

Comment: If I use fête in English prose, should I write it in italics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is ***fête***, not ***fete***, and it is a transitive verb with many “active” citations in the OED:

> fête /feɪt/, *v*.
>   Etymology: ad. Fr. *fêter*, f. *fête*: see prec.
>
> *trans*. To entertain (a person) at a fête; to feast; also, to give a fête in honour of, commemorate (some event, etc.) by a fête.
>
> - 1819 *Edin. Rev.* XXXII. 221 ― He was in general too fond of flattering and ‘feteing’ his master.
> - A. 1845 Barham *Ingol. Leg.,* Hermann, ― The murder thus out, Hermann’s fêted and thanked.
> - 1849 Thackeray *Pendennis* lxvi, ― The··two footmen··intoxicated the page at a wine-shop, to fête Laura’s recovery.
> - 1879 Huxley *Hume* 36 ― Great nobles fêted him.
> - 1892 *Nation* (N.Y.) 29 Sept. 239/2 ― The Government··judging··that the anniversary of the invasion of the Tuileries by the people··ought not to be fêted.
>
> Hence **ˈfêted** *ppl. a.*
>
> - 1828 Disraeli *Voy. Capt. Popanilla* xiii. 158 ― A habit quite refreshing to fêted characters.
> - 1852 Mrs. Smythies *Bride Elect* xxxiii, ― Fair and fêted guest as she was!

Note also that it is a person whom one fêtes, not an occasion.

---

### EDIT

Here are some festive quotations from the *Economist*:

- ... in this heinous crime spending their ill gotten gains in whichever country that fetes them, should appall anyone who has even a monochrome ...
- And Thaksin Shinawatra, Thailand's prime minister, who feted Mr Khin Nyunt as a man the world could do business with, now has egg on his ...
- Feted on his return to his troubled old firm, John Mack must justify the hype ...
- It has praised Hong Kong for its super-strict currency board, and feted Singapore for its flexible managed float.
- Mr Khumalo, who spent 12 years incarcerated on Robben Island with Nelson Mandela, was fêted when his consortium bid 54.5 rand a ...
- Feted early in the year, when his firm was buying the Jim Henson Company, creator of the Muppets, and half of Formula One, Mr Haffa is now ...
- "Those pundits who "got Iraq right" or "predicted the tech bubble collapse" are feted with speaking engagements and special television ...
- First they feted the series of events that led to the formation of the first non- communist government in September 1989, then bemoaned the Nazi ...
- Will they still fête him when he next visits Zambia?
- ... their ill gotten gains in whichever country that fêtes them, should appall anyone who has even a monochrome of respect for human rights.
- et despite an imperial style at odds with corporate-governance fashion, Wall Street fêtes Mr Raymond as, to cite Morgan Stanley, “one of the ...
- Now would seem a good time for finance to fête its own flops.
- Feted on his return to his troubled old firm, John Mack must justify the hype.
- He was fêted, in ZANU circles, for his hilarious puns linking Tony Blair with a local make of toilet.
- On March 21st, the once-fêted Mr Bon announced annual results that capped a miserable decline: a loss of euro8.3 billion
- In 2001, Iran's president, Muhammad Khatami, was fêted in Moscow.
- Metallurgist turned nuclear entrepreneur, Mr Khan, once feted in the Islamic world as the “father of Pakistan's bomb”, is now confined to one of ...
- It is regularly feted as a flourishing platform for virtual commerce, yet a large portion of its economic activity relates to sex.
- Like South Korea, China has feted its scientific stars, not just for their supposed laboratory achievements but also for the lustre they gave ...
- que la fête continue for the poors serfs.
- The man fêted last year as the Liberator of Warsaw, Berlin and Prague has already shown enough of a brutal streak in Lithuania to be dubbed ...
- China’s rulers had no choice but to fête Kim Jong Il and his entourage as, earlier this month, he stepped off a lavish train in Beijing to plead for ...
- Though the KMT lost power in Taiwan in 2000 and Mr Lien himself is likely soon to give up his party job, Chinese leaders feted him like a ...
- That journalists who once fêted Mr Blair have now turned on him says more about how he has squandered his once considerable authority and ...
- And only last month, as part of Libya's post-Lockerbie rehabilitation, Britain's Arabists assembled to fete the foppish young man at Chatham ...
- The author also did not mention that one of the soldiers who raised the flag on Iwo Jima was an American Indian who was fêted at first, came ...
- Feted rather than shunned, he was dubbed “father of development” by his fan club, and even many foreigners agreed: development banks ...
- The House should not be fêting Sinn Fein leaders ...
- This is why he is feted wherever he goes, including in South Africa, with its thriving economy that is run on sound principles and not on the ...
- The memo outlines what House Democrats have dubbed the “Campaign for a New Majority,” which debuted Tuesday night with a fundraiser fêting Missouri Rep. Richard Gephardt (Mo.) that raised roughly $2 million for the DCCC.
- It is understandable, given their country's history, that the Poles are enjoying punching above their weight and being fêted by President George ...
- There is a whiff of that from critics who derided Mr Grass in 1995 and fete him now.
- His flight to India was humiliating for China: even a young monk it had feted and nurtured to help bolster its rule in Tibet rejected it in the most ...
- Fêting Hitler's birthday is one of their pastimes; if your skin is the wrong colour, this place could be perilous.
- Unlike most towns, Cognac is literally en fête during its festival.
- Switzerland's economy is stagnating, unemployment is rising, its airline still ails, Martin Ebner, a fêted financier, has stumbled, and many Swiss ...
- This is courtesy Dr Okonjo-Iweala that the Economist so feted.
- ... many of the Tea Partiers seem to espouse but was appalled to see the convention goers fêting the likes of Sarah Palin and Tom Tancredo.
- Fêting the Chinese president with the full honours accorded to America's most welcome visitors will help.
- By fêting the novelist, Mr Castro gained an internationally acclaimed ambassador at large.
- When he launched the British presidency six months ago with a fête at Waterloo Station, the prime minister said he saw the presidency as a test ...
- He became a world figure in literature, much admired in Germany and fêted in Scandinavia.
- And the fêting of prominent technology projects in emerging economies is sometimes premature.
- Still, fêting Gerry Adams, head of Sinn Fein, the political wing of the IRA, at the White House St Patrick's Day party was unhelpful to both Tony ...
- ... he has aligned himself with Ahmed of Qatar and Rashed of Dubai and it is noticeable that the Iranians have taken trouble to fête him on his ...

Comment: Your 1892 citation is in the passive voice.

Comment: @PeterShor I gave the full citation set to illustrate the balance of active to passive.

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear from your text.

Comment: Just for completeness, the 1845 citation is also passive.

Comment: In the 1849 and 1892 citations events, not persons, are fêted.

Answer (score 3):

**Fete** as a transitive verb means: (Chambers)

> To entertain at a feast
>
> To honour with festivities

So you can't *fete* occasions, but you can certainly fete people.

> She feted her guests at the party.
>
> We have to fete our soldiers.

Comment: If I wanted to illustrate, I could say ...'fete' our soldiers with accolades and banquets? Or does doing so make it redundant or reduce the impact of fete?

Comment: O yes, you could definitely say that. It won't reduce the impact.

Comment: tchrist's answer provides a definition and citations in which occasions are fêted

Comment: @StoneyB: It is current usage anyway. There is only so much an 1892 OED sentence can stand for.

Comment: @Shyam Well, every time I remember encountering fête as a noun (mostly in murder mysteries set in English villages) it denoted a event of some sort raising money for a charity or observing some occasion in the ecclesiastical calendar; and as a highly proficient user of the language I'm entitled to overlook the silence of contemporaries, appeal to precedent,and fête anything I damn well please!

Comment: @Shyam And this - a headline from CBC News (http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/story/2012/08/06/stub-jamaica-independence-drummond.html) dated yesterday: "Jamaica's golden jubilee feted across Canada".

Answer (score 1):

"Also note that you don't fête an occasion - if you must use it as a verb, you fête a person."

This is not true in the original French version, where you can fête your birthday, etc...  Note that the circumflex denotes the absence of a letter that was elided in speech in French, in this and many other cases an 's', so 'fête' is not that far from 'feast'.

Comment: The fact remains there are only 10 relevant instances of *"fete the occasion"* in Google Books, as opposed to tens of thousands for *"**celebrate** the occasion"*.

Answer (score -2):

My advice is to stick with the passive voice. As [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they%20feted%20him,he%20was%20feted&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, that's what most people do...

[image]

And [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20feted%20him%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are just half-a-dozen instances of *"I feted him"* in the entire corpus of Google Books. You can get away with passive voice, or non-specific subject *(they, the people, etc.)*, but in general *"to fete"* isn't often used as an "active" verb. Semantically, the "real" subject is actually the person being feted, not the people delivering that honour.

Also note that you don't *fete an occasion* - if you must use it as a verb, you *fete a **person***.

Comment: That is a clear misuse of Ngrams: those are not comparable things.  Who is to say that he was fêted by them?  There may be others.  And if you look for just *fêted him*, then you have problems in the other side.  This makes no sense. It is misleading.

Comment: I agree with tchrist. If you look at the Ngram Viewer for [he was feted,feted him](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+feted%2Cfeted+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) you'll see that there is only a 2:1 advantage for the passive. (Of course this comparison has its own problems, as tchrist points out.)

Comment: The entire approach of surface-level grepping that doesn’t understand
English grammar is fatally flawed. It’s so full of false positives and
false negatives as to render it useless. The problems w/this **should** be self-evident. *Fêted him* is not a complete VP; it is just a non-finite participle plus an immediate object.
On the other side can be any number of intervening words, like *he hadn’t ever been so fêted*.
That’s a FN, and there are infinitely more where that one came from. You can even get FPs like “of the happy couple they fêted, him more her”. Ngrams is WAY hard to use usefully.

Comment: Of course he can “actively” *fête* someone! There can be no question. If you can’t pull out more examples of *will fête* than there are chinamen in China Town, you aren’t even trying. Your obsession with English used only since grade-school children were born is ill-placed; it does a disservice to the tongue and the children alike. Again, I will believe you put any real trust in all this fly-by-night Google N-gram majoritarianism as soon as you upgrade your archaic spelling to what ngrams clearly proves is the majority norm, and not a moment before.

Comment: The verb-anything principle doesn’t apply here, because *fête* is already a verb; I await your data supporting your notion that these people clearly *fêting* others are verbing **fête** the noun out of ignorance of *fête* the verb. Once again your “common makes right” argument rings hollow when you do not follow your own advice. Even worse is the apparent notion that people shouldn’t pay attention to anything that happened before they were born.

Comment: @tchrist: Check your OED again. It seems clear to me fete the noun came first. You apparently think that just because a usage was actually recorded 200 years ago it should therefore be reasonable today. I don't say the past is *irrelevant*, but it's pretty useless as a guide to what could *reasonably* be used today.

Comment: Suppose a mindlessly misleading Google N-Gram somehow correctly identifies usage A as occurring twice as frequently as usage B over the last 20 years. You keep telling people that means they need to use usage A.  That's ridiculous.

Comment: Reading the OP's exact question, he asked whether *fête* could be used in the active voice. The simplest and most direct answer is one trivially answered by dictionaries and books alike: yes, of course it can. That is his answer. Your dubious Google N-Grams that attempt to somehow infer absolute correctness from mere popularity not only fail to answer the question, they confuse the question with a non-answer to a question never asked.

Comment: My initial problem was your dodgy use of Google N-Grams, but the most important point is that you have failed to answer the OP's question – which, to remind you, is "How can I use *fête* in the active voice?" Instead of answering his question, you try to impute correctness based on popularity, which even though it is based on disputed data, still shows no overwhelming majority and thus does not justify your evasive and prescriptive commands to the poor OP.

Comment: Comments are not a good place for discussion. Please take your thread to a new chat room.  Thank you.

Comment: Noted, KitFox. @Paola: No offense, but I've reversed your edit because I accept *fete* as an ***English*** word. I consider *fête, café,* etc. to be ***French*** words, which I've no desire to promulgate on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. As you prefer, both because it's your language more than mine, and because I probably edited your answer as well. Still, I was writing what is found in dictionaries (and also trying to give uniformity of spelling, as throughout this exchange, both in the post and some answers, the word is written in its original way). And I would **never** accept anyone writing *spagetti*, whatever pronunciation you might get out of it!

Comment: @Paola: Well, it's tchrist's language as well, and the very first sentence of his answer stoutly defends the accent. Which I'm not sufficiently bothered about to actually take issue with, but I'd rather not be railroaded into apparently agreeing with. I do agree with you that *spagetti* is simply a misspelling, but I wouldn't correct, say, *dialog* instead of *dialogue*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Nor would I, as much as I never add *me* to *program* or double the 'l' in *traveled*. As for *spagetti*, I was defending my right as an Italian to the right spelling of the word.

Comment: @Paola: Anyway, I'm content you understand why I actually *wanted* to use the non-accented version (as opposed to "couldn't be bothered to construct the character"). I don't know why a couple of people have downvoted the answer. Maybe they think I *should* have the accent - but it's my answer, so I'll say what I like.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. You may be right. Actually, the answer by Shyam has received a downvote too, whereas the other two, tchrist's and mwwhitesf's, have not and they spell the verb differently...

Comment: @Paola: It's irritating if people downvote for reasons tangential to the specific issue under discussion, but I doubt there's much can be done about it. This is a weird question anyway. Three out of four answers peripherally address the fact that we're not overkeen on *feting/feteing an **occasion***. And the other answer (comment, really) just tells us that if we were French we'd have no such misgivings.